# Return const struct member as non const in C: ok or bad?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, constants

Is it ok or can it be considered a bad practice to return non `const` data member pointer from a `const struct`? What are the dangers of returning a non `const` pointer as shown below?

```
widget_t * widget_child(const widget_t * parent)
{
if (!parent)
    return NULL;

return parent->child;
}
```

Comment: This depends on the semantics of a `widget_t`, which you haven't described. Is it OK to modify the child of a `const widget_t`, or should `const widget_t` mean a widget where you cannot modify it or any of its descendants?

Comment: What is more problematic is `char *strchr(const char *str, char c)` from the Standard library.  Here, you have to return a non-constant pointer to a position in the constant string.  C++ does not like this; it breaks its notion of const-correctness.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's the reason C++ replaces this function with two functions having the same semantics aside from preserving const-correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it is acceptable to return a specific non-`const` data member from a `const`-qualified `struct`depends entirely on the semantics of the data-structure it is a part of.
It is not legally wrong, and C cannot say anything more on the subject.
You, as the programmer, who (hopefully) knows and understands the semantics are trusted (out of neccessity / for efficiency) to choose right.

Even if it *was* `const`-qualified, C deliberately allows you to override it *if you are sure you are right and accept the consequences.* This override takes the form of an explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. Pointers themselves are values (it's an address, after all). You read that value from a `const` structure. That's fine. You return that value. That's also fine.

Comment: If you throw away `const`-ness on a whim like this, what's the point in using `const` at all?

Comment: Notice though, the code doesn't return anything that allows the caller to modify the struct `*parent`. Thus, this code respects `*parent`'s constness. There's nothing `const` about `*(parent->child)`.

Comment: A const struct could be in the read only memory, and have the child pointer pointing to a read only memory as well. Throwing away const seems danger. Right?

Comment: @emmet and guest:  the question is whether widget_t::child is a pointer to a widget_t or a pointer to a const widget_t.

Comment: Yes, you're right. If `parent->child` points at something mutable, then there's probably nothing wrong with it. The question is whether `const`-ness does or should be considered to propagate to children. Technically, I'm pretty sure it doesn't. Philosophically, I'm not sure it shouldn't.

Comment: @emmet: if child is not a const pointer, assigning the address of a const object to it will generate a compiler warning. That would be the problem, but the code in the OP is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` keyword doesn't really define anything constant in C. What it says is basically a promise to the compiler: the `const` identifier will be treated readonly within this specific context. `const` should be read as `readonly`, this was bad naming from the beginning of C.

This will allow the compiler to do certain optimizations it couldn't do if it suspected the callee to modify this identifier within the called function.

Baseline is: this is perfectly legal since the promise is kept.